# Find which files were updated in a commit in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am triggering AWS CodePipeline with a PR commit through Bitbucket.
Is there any way I can find which files were updated/created with the latest commit?

I looked into the [Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) and I looked into the pipeline's details and history CLI commands:
`$ aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions --pipeline-name <name>` and
`$ aws codepipeline get-pipeline-state --name <name>` but they don't have the information I need.

Why do I need this?
The pipeline triggers one or more Airflow DAGs and listens to their status. We include the DAG name(s) in the branch name, we parse it using CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF and we trigger the DAG(s). This is error-prone, and since the DAG names match their filename we would like to extract them automatically.

Is it something doable? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where would you like to find the diff? As a build for the PR, or in the build after merging? Any way `git diff` can be of help? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-version. Make sure you use the full clone version of codepipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310000/aws-codepipeline-build-lacks-git-history. Didn't try it myself though

Comment: I would like to get it during the build for the PR. I'll test if I can use `git diff`. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the commit hash from the pipeline execution.
when using cli:

`aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions --pipeline-name <pipeline-name>`

you get a list of executions, the first execution is the latest one.

```
pipelineExecutionSummaries: [ 
    { ...
       sourceRevisions: [
         {
             ...
             revisionId: "<commit-hash>"
          }
        ]
    }
...
]
```

then when you have the commit hash you can get the files that are modified in that commit

`git diff-tree --stat <commit-hash>`

further logic depending on your application you can handle when you got the files that are modified.